Can not login lubuntu system: apscustomer account
when I restart system (lubuntu), it require account and password, I input right account & password but it just login and logout immediately.

You've provided few specifics; for starters we don't know your Lubuntu release..  however the reason for a login loop can be many. They can result from a change made in the prior session by a user with sudo rights, a lack of disk space in $HOME (your user directory), but TEXT LOGINS (eg. Ctrl+Alt+F4 to switch to text terminal) will still work, allowing you to login & check out what went wrong (ie. lack of disk space; or if changes were made you can peruse apt logs to remind yourself what was done etc)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
